# Circular Dependency in DAX calculated column::AAS model

Tags: dax, calculated-columns, circular-dependency, powerbi-desktop, azure-analysis-services

I am stuck in the situation where I am adding a new calculated column but it's prompting me the circular dependency. The first column is calculated like:

```
=VAR Denominator = ( Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedClosedDateVsFirstPurchaseDate] + 1 )
VAR Sales =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( SalesR48NBVBySolution[TotalSales] ),
        FILTER (
            SalesR48NBVBySolution,
            SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate] >= Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstAnchorPurchaseDateAfterGTWClosedDate]
        )
    )
VAR R6AnchorSales =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( SalesR48NBVBySolution[TotalSales] ),
        FILTER (
            SalesR48NBVBySolution,
            SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate]
                >= EDATE (
                    Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstAnchorPurchaseDateAfterGTWClosedDate],
                    -6
                )
                && SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate] < Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstAnchorPurchaseDateAfterGTWClosedDate]
                && SalesR48NBVBySolution[ClensedAnchorDesignation] = "Y"
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( R6AnchorSales ),
        IF ( NOT (ISBLANK ( Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstAnchorPurchaseDateAfterGTWClosedDate] )
            )
                && ISBLANK ( R6AnchorSales ),
            DIVIDE ( Sales, Denominator ) * 12
        )
    )
```

The next column I want to create here is:

```
=VAR Denominator = ( Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedClosedDateVsFirstPurchaseDate_SLN] + 1 )
VAR Sales =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( SalesR48NBVBySolution[TotalSales] ),
        FILTER (
            SalesR48NBVBySolution,
            SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate] >= Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstPurchasedateAfterGTWClosedDate_SLN]
        )
    )
VAR R6AnchorSales =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( SalesR48NBVBySolution[TotalSales] ),
        FILTER (
            SalesR48NBVBySolution,
            SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate]
                >= EDATE (
                    Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstPurchasedateAfterGTWClosedDate_SLN],
                    -6
                )
                && SalesR48NBVBySolution[invoicedate] < Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstPurchasedateAfterGTWClosedDate_SLN]
                && SalesR48NBVBySolution[ClensedAnchorDesignation] = "N"  &&  CALCULATE(MAX('CAM Alignment'[NodeCd_L3])=="C3-10-00015")

        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( R6AnchorSales ),
        IF ( NOT (ISBLANK ( Validation_Accounts_Agreements[CalculatedFirstPurchasedateAfterGTWClosedDate_SLN] )
            )
                && ISBLANK ( R6AnchorSales ),
            DIVIDE ( Sales, Denominator ) * 12
        )
    )
```

Here is more info about my model::

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the above picture, the yellow highlighted columns I am using to create the calculated column 1 (calculated Annualization).The red circled columns are being used to create column 2 ( calculated Annualization_SLN).both sets of columns are almost similar (changes in the filter).But when I am trying to create column 2 ( calculated Annualization_SLN) that time I am getting this error of circular dependency; which is dependent on column 1.

Comment: Can you clean up your table and columns to be more readable rather than having crazy-long names? It would also help to include the names of the calculated column in their definition.

Comment: @vishal in general, we do not need to know the exact name of every column, however, it is important to know (1) the name of the first column you are creating and (2) which column is calculated and which is a data column (pulled from the back-end as-is)

Answer (score 1):

In general, according to best-practice avoid extensively using Calculated Columns. Instead, add them in your data source (back-end) or use M-Query.

In order to answer your question precisely, you need to share more information about your model (i.e. relationships). However, we can provide you some guidelines referring to [this](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/) article in order to avoid circular dependencies.

Quoting the conclusion of the article:

> Most of the time, circular dependencies occur when you use calculated tables. You can easily avoid them by paying attention to your choice of functions. The difference between DISTINCT and VALUES, or between ALL and ALLNOBLANKROW is a subtle difference. But once you get used to it, your code will be safer when it comes to relationships and circular references.

Comment: @vishalpundir you would need more information about your model: entities, relationships, calculated columns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you pl undelete my post..as I dont know how to paste the screen shot in comments that why I post additional information in the Answer box

Comment: @Seymour...I focused on the relationships and found that two table (Validation and Sales) both are connected through bridge table and bidirectional relationship.When I remove this bidirectional to single directional the circular dependency has automatically removed but when I checked the results those are not properly populating.Is there anything we can alternatively use ??Pl suggest!!!

Comment: @vishalpundir (1) Avoid bidirectional relationship in the model unless you know exactly what you are doing because there might be side-effects (reference: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/bidirectional-relationships-and-ambiguity-in-dax/). (2) There are infinite alternatives, one is to enable the bi-directional relationship ONLY for the specific calculation you need (https://dax.guide/crossfilter/). Does this help? Otherwise we need more information about your data model and what is your goal.

Comment: @Seymour..Thanks for the alternate..but after using Crossfilter DAX again its giving me the same circular dependency.Before that i have removed Bidirectional relation.

Comment: Here I am using the bridge table and unique records in that and botrh tables are connected through bidirectional relations.  Other approach that I have tried is  1.)  I have created those calculated columns in bridge table but data was not populated in report. 2.) I have created a unique identifier in Table 1 and and connect that with other table in 1-* relation that time circular dependency has been removed but again data was not correct in model.  3.) by removing the bidirectional from the table

Comment: Then you need to present more information about your data model and what you are trying to do. Also try to keep examples as simple as possible but representative of your problem. You can create a new question or update this one.

Comment: Is there any way/or another forum I can show you the snaps of my data model?

Comment: I have added some more info about model in the question